# How do I propagate errors from tokio::spawn's future?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

When the `http_service.call()` function is called, a `Result` is returned and I want to propagate it to the function calling `run()`.

```
 pub async fn run(config: BootingInfo) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    ...
    loop {
        ...
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            http_service.call(connection).await;
        });
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I tried the following but failed.

```
tokio::spawn(async move {
    http_service.call(connection).await?;
});
```

How do I propagate errors from `tokio::spawn`'s future?

Comment: I think with `spawn` there is no chance to propagate the error back, because the code could be executed in a different thread; the control flow is not linear and asynchronous.

Comment: `spawn` returns a future that can be `await`ed to get the result of the inner future. But of course in that case you don't need to spawn and can simply call `http_service.call (connection).await?` directly in your `run` function.

Comment: If you want to communicate errors back to the `loop` in `run` while also allowing the calls to run independently, then you could probably use a channel that the loop can check during each iteration if any spawned calls had failed.

Comment: @kmdreko or collect the futures into a vector and use [`futures::future::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.21/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) to `await` them all at once (assuming that the `loop` isn't really infinite of course).

Comment: the 5th example of handling a [`tokio::task::JoinHandle` here](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.0/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html) shows that you need `??` on the handle to unwrap both the `spawn`'s result as well as your `http_service.call` result

Comment: @Jmb `.await`ed `spawn()` is not the same as without `spawn()`: it guarantees termination even if the future drops. This can be important with e.g. `select!`.